# I've changed ISP, now www access to my website is not working, but HTTP is

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address, isp

I've inherited a company's IT position, so I was not in on the original configuration. We have recently changed our ISP (several months ago). Our Domain is hosted by Network Solutions and their A Records have been updated.

The setup is this:

We have three servers

1. Domain Controller (server 2008r2)
2. Exchange 2010 running on server 2008r2
3. NAV running on server 2008r2

The website is on the exchange server.

I've updated the A Records (including the www) at the Domain Host to the static IP address Cox assigned us `24.255.xxx.xxx`. Mail and everything else works great. That is, except for our website using www.xxxxxx.com (that gives a 404 error) `http://xxxxxx.com` works fine.

When I'm outside the network and ping the `www.xxxxxx.com` I get the IP address Cox gave us. When I do an NSLOOKUP I get an IP address of a Cox DNS Server `68.105.xxx.xxx`. If I do the same steps while on the network I get a local IP Address `192.168.xxx.xxx` (same results on the NSLOOKUP).

I'm stumped and have tried everything I found on this site and many others.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get a 200 on both `xxxxxx.com` and on `www.xxxxxx.com`.

Comment: When using nslookup, you can test using an outside DNS server by specifying it as the second argument. Test this using, say, `nslookup www.xxxxxx.com 8.8.8.8` and `nslookup www.xxxxxx.com 8.8.8.8`. You can do that from inside your network. Post back whether that works correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

What does your internal network's DNS configuration look like?

Your local server seems to be giving an internal address for the web server, which would be necessary to access the web server in a hairpin NAT scenario; was the website formerly hosted inside the network?

You should:

- Determine which address you need to use when inside the network to successfully connect to the web server - sounds like it should be using the public address.
- Verify via hosts file that the address works as expected when it's resolved as that name
- Update your internal DNS configuration to return the correct address for queries to that name

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this is a host header problem in IIS. But I'll get to that in a sec, for now here's a general troubleshooting guide for you to follow:

1. If you're using an internet facing DNS server and try to resolve www.xxxxxx.com and xxxxxx.com, make sure that both of them are forwarding to the correct static IP address of your company have.
2. If you're using a LAN facing DNS server, make sure that the same records above resolve to your internal IP address of the web server (in your case, the exchange one)
3. If you're using an application level firewall, insure that www.xxxxxx.com and xxxxxx.com are allowed in and can be routed to the internal IIS server. this vary depending on your firewall type.
4. Make sure that the company web site in your IIS have host headers for www.xxxxxx.com and xxxxxx.com, this is needed in order to let incoming requests for the mentioned domain names to go to the correct site since you're using multiple sites in IIS, more info can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps.